# How to convert or burn a .DMG image file on Windows?

Tags: windows, dvd, iso-image, burning, dmg-image

What software can be recommended to burn a Mac created .DMG file on a Windows operating system? Ideally it should be free, or at least reasonably priced.

Or, as an alternative, an application convert it to .ISO or something equivalent?

I'm looking for reassurance I won't be wasting several (more expensive than normal DVDs) dual layer DVDs to get this done right. As the .DMG file is 7 GB.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Personally, I like [MagicISO](http://www.magiciso.com/FAQ/FAQ0011.htm).

Comment: MagicISO was struggling with some of my .DMG files but worked with others.

Answer (score 8):

I have used [dmg2img](http://vu1tur.eu.org/tools/) with success.

1. Download `dmg2img`.
2. Extract it with your favorite ZIP utility (for example, [7-zip](http://www.7-zip.org/)) into a new folder.

   [image]
3. Holy <kbd>Shift</kbd> and right-click the folder, then click **Open command window here**.

   [image]
4. Simply call `dmg2img` with the file name of your `.dmg` file as the first parameter
   <sup>(Hint, you can drag & drop the file into the command prompt to get the file name inserted on the command line).</sup>

   [image]

Comment: So now you have a "Standard HFS+" image. On a windows computer...congratulations! You can now...do what?

Comment: Burn it. The question was how to either directly burn or "[...]convert it to .ISO or something equivalent". Most software for windows knows how to burn .img

Comment: @user221931: After conversion .dmg expanded from 4Gb to 15Gb, won't fit  on any DVD. Useless operation.

Answer (score 0):

This is what worked for me:

I have Windows 7 64-bit and needed to burn a 6.36 GB 10.6.3 Snow Leopard image to a DL DVD on my PC to install on a Macbook Pro. I am no stranger to PCs as a repair technician, but I have little experience with Macs.

I used Power ISO 4.7 in Windows 7, selected the "Tools"  and then the "burn" pull down menu. Point to the .DMG image file on your PC and have a DVD/CD in the burner big enough to hold the image, select your burn speed and that is it.

Hold the "C" down after you press the power button on the Mac and hear the Apple tone to boot to the new image.

I did use my Windows 7 DVD to wipe all partitions from the Macbook as that was what I was familiar with. I was then able to create a new partition with the Mac OS DVD I created.